# How to avoid duplication in Bulk API

Tags: api, bulk-api

I have 3 million records(Accounts and contacts) in my product.I wanted to push all the data into salesforce. I use Bulk API Pk chunking to do this.How can I avoid duplicate record creation(in Accounts or contacts) while using BULK API.I am really stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can set up duplicate rules and then use the data loader.
Normally, it will not ignore the rule (if active)

Here is a link for duplicate rules :
https://help.salesforce.com/articleViewid=duplicate_rules_create.htm&language=en_US&type=0